# PHP - Get a reference to an element from a multidimensional array by using string as key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

is there an easy, non-eval-using method for getting a reference to an element of a multidimensional array? The key should be passed as a string.

Here's an example:

`getSessionReference('1.4.2', $arrReference);`

should return a reference to

`$_SESSION['1']['4']['2']`

and so a call like

`$arrReference['foo'] = 'bar';`

would change it to

`$_SESSION['1']['4']['2']['foo'] = 'bar'`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for clarity. But I have to ask if you can you give a real example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Whatever he tries to do, he does it completely wrong

Comment: @Scorpion - maybe so, but in that case we're here to help him! :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld He would not listen to us :)

Comment: A good real world example is wanting to give the code a reference to only a part of the session array. This way, you keep storage of session vars for different code bases and modules well separated. In large projects, especially ones which evolve over years with many developers coming and going, these types of engineering decisions can sometimes be useful.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld and Scorpion: Excuse me for the late answer. It's exactly about, what rambo coder says. 

If you have some other approach, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$arr[5][6][7] = 111;

$cursor =& $arr;
foreach (explode('.', '5.6') as $key) {
    $cursor =& $cursor[$key];
}

var_dump($arr);
var_dump($cursor);
$cursor['foo'] = 5;
var_dump($arr);
var_dump($cursor);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/XUEhMj

or in function form

```
function & getSessionRef($keyPath) {
    $cursor =& $_SESSION;
    foreach (explode('.', $keyPath) as $key) {
        $cursor =& $cursor[$key];
    }
    return $cursor;
}

$cursor =& getSessionRef('a.6');
```

btw - I used the php feature named [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) in that code, where you see the ampersand like `=&`.

Comment: hey, shouldn't 'foo' be an index in the "7" array?

Comment: @Charles why? I didn't specify any index 7 in my key path for the reference.

Comment: @rambocoder That's 99 percent the approach I used before, but I messed up the referencing somehow, so each loop cycle added trash to the session. :-/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use pass-by-reference.

```
function getReference($key, &$arr)
{
    $e = explode('.', $key);
    foreach ($_SESSION[$e[0]][$e[1]][$e[2]] as $k => &$v)
        $arr[$k] = $v;
}

$arr = array();
getReference("1.4.2", $arr);
```

p.s.: this does not actually return the reference but it serves your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are after:

```
function &getSessionReference($keyStr, &$session) {
    $keys = explode('.', $keyStr);
    $temp = &$session;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $temp = &$temp[$key];
    }
    return $temp;
}

$_SESSION['1']['4']['2'] = [];
$arrReference = &getSessionReference('1.4.2', $_SESSION);
$arrReference['foo'] = 'bar';

echo json_encode($_SESSION);

// {"1":{"4":{"2":{"foo":"bar"}}}}
```